# Как мне сконвертировать 'State' в 'int'?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

Я хочу умножить определённый текст на то - сколько задал пользователь.

То есть для примера:

- Бот - Сколько бубликов ты хочешь?
- Человек - 5
- Бот - бублик бублик бублик бублик бублик

Вот как я это вижу:

```
class how_many(StatesGroup):
    count = State()


async def kiss(message: types.Message):
    await how_many.count.set()
    await message.reply('Сколько бубликов хочешь?')


async def to_kiss(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.reply ("Бублик" * int(how_many.count))
    await State.finish()


def handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(kiss, commands='kiss', state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(to_kiss, state=how_many.count)
```

Получаю ошибку в виде: " int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'State' "

**Не важное:**
*Хендлеры отправляют ответ в другой файл*

Comment: Укажите откуда State берете. Возможно, у `State` есть свойство `value`: `dp.register_message_handler(to_kiss, state=how_many.count.value)`

Comment: Извиняюсь, совсем забыл, вот:
`class how_many(StatesGroup):
    count = State()`
Проверил, свойства value нет
('State' object has no attribute 'value')

Comment: Перефразирую, откуда вы его импортируете? `from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State`?

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @gil9red Да, именно оттуда.

Comment: У State значение строковое, нет int: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/df294e579f104e2ae7e9f37b0c69490782d33091/aiogram/dispatcher/filters/state.py#L27-L38 . Судя по примеру https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html#aiogram.Dispatcher.register_message_handler в `state=` нужно строку передавать (странно, что там вообще про int ругалось, если бы приложили стек с ошибкой я бы посмотрел что пошло не так :) ), т.е. думаю так: `dp.register_message_handler(to_kiss, state=how_many.count.state)`

Comment: А для чего? Что вы хотите увидеть здесь `how_many.count`